# FacebookOAuthException: Error validating access token on WP7 using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a strange problem with the Facebook C# SDK on Windows Phone 7. I am using the SDK to post pictures to users' walls. For the first authentication and the first few posts, it works great. After a while (I have a feeling the magic cutoff is 24hrs) I start to get an error on every post:

> FacebookOAuthException was unhandled
>
> (OAuthException) Error validating access token.

This happens after my line of code that does the actual post has run...

```
m_facebook.PostAsync(@"/photos", parameters, PostComplete);
```

... but before my PostComplete callback function is called. No code of mine is running when the exception happens. My Application_UnhandledException is *not* called - I get the error in a dialog in the middle of the screen in VS, and it says that no source code is available.

If this exception means I need to show the login screen again, that's fine - right now I'm both not sure what it means and not sure how to trap the bugger. Any help appreciated.

Chris

Comment: I have the same problem. When for example somebody removes the permissions on facebook. I want to catch the exception when something goes wrong but I have no idea how to do that because it throws the oAuthException without calling any of my code.

Answer (score 0):

What [publishing permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) do you use?

By default, access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application.

For getting a long-lived access token, you need to ask for the **offline_access** permission.

Comment: it doesn't matter what permissions I use. I want to catch the error when I try to post without the correct permissions because that can change when I store the token. Even e long-lived token can't solve that because a user could manually remove the permissions for my application in facebook. I want to catch that exception

Comment: I've given this a try, many thanks - this does explain what my error means and how to work around it. However, as Matthijs says, this doesn't actually solve the problem of how to deal with this exception when it does come up (e.g. in the situation he mentions).